# I'm having trouble finding my ID Engine for the GPT I created using the GPT builder. ( OpenAI)

Tags: swift, openai-api

Here is my code for Swift and the section where I'm having trouble with:

```
import Foundation

class GPTManager {
    private let apiKey = "MY KEY HERE"
    private let session = URLSession.shared
    private let baseUrl = "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/YOUR_ENGINE_ID/completions"

    func getResponse(prompt: String, completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl) else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("Bearer \(apiKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let body: [String: Any] = [
            "prompt": prompt,
            "max_tokens": 100
        ]

        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: [])

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }

            if let responseDictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any],
               let text = responseDictionary["choices"] as? [[String: Any]],
               let firstChoice = text.first,
               let finalText = firstChoice["text"] as? String {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(finalText.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))
                }
            } else {
                completion(nil)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

I'm supposed to put my engine Id where it states here :
(https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/YOUR_ENGINE_ID/completions)
but can't seem to find it. Where can I find it.

Comment: Is your whole question simply asking what value to use for `YOUR_ENGINE_ID` in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this endpoint,
"https://api.openai.com/v1/completions" and include the model type
in the request body, for example:

```
 let body: [String: Any] = ["model": "davinci-002",
                            "prompt": prompt,
                            "max_tokens": 100]
```

Note the deprecations and legacy changes at [deprecations](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations).

It is best to use this endpoint "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions"
when using more recent models. You will need to send a chat message to it.

You could add, for example `davinci-002`, as the model id in your url,

```
private let baseUrl = "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci-002/completions"
```

but AFAIK it is best to use the more recent endpoints, see https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation